# How to use 'between' in CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to select Shift from my production table such that if the time time is between 05:00 PM to 06:30 AM it is Shift B else  its Shift A. The SQL that I have written is quite simple but does not gives me the expected results. The SQL is

```
declare @time varchar(50)
set @time= (select time = convert(varchar,getdate(),108))

select Shift_FK_ID from production
where op_Date='2021-08-23' and Shift_FK_ID=
(CASE WHEN @time between '17:00:00' and  '06:30:00' 
Then '2'
Else '1'
End)
```

The Result I get is

Shift_FK_ID 
1
1
1

Where op_Date is operations date. The code was simple but can't figure it out. Maybe it has something to do with 24 hrs format.

Help required.

Regards

Comment: Surely `@time` should just be a `time`, no? The problem is your data type, not the `CASE` **expression**. `DECLARE @time time(0) = GETDATE()`.

Comment: If you filter for a specific date, your query might not include all of the shifts that you desired. It might not include "shifts" that started on the previous date but ended on the current date depending on what the column `op_date` represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want logic like this:

```
select (case when convert(time, getdate()) between '06:30:00' and '17:00:00'
             then 1 else 2
        end) as shift
```

There is no need to use strings for these comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff... I should've thought of that